# Our force.com site is not available

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites

It is just happening!! All of visualforce can not open.

[image]

DNS resolves nothing return.

[image]

Even switch to Salesforce's DNS Server, it can not be resolved.

Salesforce's DNS Server problem !!

[image]

Comment: It's working again!

Comment: AP15, AP18 and NA174 works again

Comment: This seems like an ongoing issue, please refrain from answering "I am also facing this issue",

Comment: Trust Salesforce has an incident on this: https://status.salesforce.com/generalmessages/464

Comment: Welcome new SFSE users finding this question via search. Please *do not post "Me too" answers*. Post an answer if you can add information to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem, but was rolled back pretty quickly

https://status.salesforce.com/generalmessages/464

> At 5:59 AM UTC, June 03 2020, the Salesforce Technology team became
>   aware of a service disruption, affecting customers ability to access
>   force.com domain. The Salesforce Technology team identified a recent
>   Domain Name Server (DNS) configuration change to be the likely cause
>   of the issue and successfully rolled back the DNS change across the
>   force.com domain, which brought most of the customers out of impact.
>
> While the Salesforce Technology team continued to validate the
>   normalised state of services, additional issues were reported by
>   customers across a few other domains. As a best and immediate path to
>   resolution, the technology team initiated a full roll back of the DNS
>   Configuration change across all the domains in production and Test. As
>   of 8:39 AM UTC, June 03, the rollback has been successfully completed
>   across the Production domains. The services have been validated and
>   confirmed to be out of impact.
>
> Should the Customers still continue to experience issues while
>   accessing the Salesforce services, please remain advised to clear the
>   browser cache on individual machines. Should clearing of the browser
>   cache not resolve the issues, the customers are advised to clear the
>   DNS cache on their individual machines.
>
> We thank you for the continued business support and patience. Posted
>   4:48 pm AEST, Jun 03 · Last updated 7:14 pm AEST, Jun 03